# Modify Element of Struct Array

Tags: java, shaders, glsl, lwjgl, struct

I have this struct array in GLSL.

```
struct Test {
    vec2 value1;
    vec3 value2;
    float value3;
}
uniform Test u_test[5];
```

How can I modify the elements of this array one at a time?

I know that the location of individual objects in an element in the array can be accessed using `glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_test[0].value1")` but I'd like to upload an entire instance of Test at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to set the value of a struct as a whole, since there is no location for it.

All of my lookups returned `-1`. The values of a struct have to be set individually.